# port-forward through a revser-proxy got 'error upgrading connection' error

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, api-gateway, gloo

I have written a simple reverse proxy which will proxy requests to a K8s cluster. The reverse proxy is deployed in a cluster which use `gloo` as api gateway.

I can perform `kubectl get pods` operations outside the cluster, using the reverse proxy to proxy kubectl requests to kube-apiserver: `kubectl -> gloo -> simple reverse proxy -> kube-apiserver`

But when I do `kubectl portward` I find that the request gets exception at `POST /api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/pods/<pod name>/portforward` with exception info `error: error upgrading connection`:
[image]

From the exception, it seems that gloo does not support the `http` to `spdy` protocol upgrade. How to solve this problem?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with kubectl v1.24 (there was some proxying / websocket related fixes, recently). If that doesn't help, then the issue is with your proxy: try something simpler first (apache/nginx/...)

Comment: @SYN I have tried `kubectl-1.22.2` and `kubectl-1.24.1` and got the same error `error upgrading connection`. This problem may be related to `gloo`, and it is still unclear how gloo's support for protocol upgrading (http->spdy) is configured...

Comment: It seems that `Envoy` doesn't support `spdy`. `gloo` is based on `Envoy` and so `gloo` doesn't support `spdy`:
- https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/http/http_connection_management
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89163